Неблокирующий канал с буфером
Помогите сообразить, как сделать следующее, желательно в "го-стиле".
Есть рутина, которая запускает консольную утилиту и парсит её вывод.
Данные идут порциями, их частота от меня никак не зависит. Может быть 10+ пакетов в секунду, может 1.
Вторая рутина должна брать эти пакеты, немного их обработать и отправить на внешний веб-сервис.
Изначально идея была - делаем канал между этими двуми рутинами. Парсим пакет - записываем в канал - читаем с канала - отправляем.
Всё хорошо, пока связь стабильная и быстрая. Как только связь теряется, тормозит - начинается затык.
Данные сыпятся быстрее, чем мы можем их отправлять.
Важно, что потеря части данных не критична, главное чтобы последние N пакетов держались в памяти и по возможности отправлялись.
Напрашивается что-то типа очереди с автоматическим удалением старых элементов при превышении лимита N.
Первая горутина туда кладёт, вторая оттуда достаёт.
То есть другими словами, нужно сделать такой канал с буфером, который бы при записи в него не блокировал (если в канале уже N элементов - самое старое значение удаляется, новое добавляется),
а при чтении - блокировал (при отсутствии данных).
Станадртный буферизированный канал не подходит - при заполненном буфере он блокирует запись.
Так как в го я новичок - трудно сообразить как такое наколхозить. Попробовал поискать по репам/гуглу - ничего похожего найти не могу.
Подскажите, куда копать, где можно подсмотреть что-то похожее?

Выглядит как будто бы вам нужно написать свою реализацию канала, причем такого, в котором новое значение затирало бы старое даже если старое еще не вытащено. Как будто бы можно использовать ring buffer и комбинацию мьютекса и кондвара для синхронизации двух горутин.

Вроде разобрался сам, всё оказалось проще чем представлялось. В сценарии с один писателем-читателем должно работать без ошибок, насколько я понимаю.
type StackBuffer[T any] struct {
    capacity int
    out      chan T
}

func NewStackBuffer[T any](capacity int) *StackBuffer[T] {
    return &StackBuffer[T]{
        capacity: capacity,
        out:      make(chan T, capacity),
    }
}

func (q *StackBuffer[T]) Push(value T) {
    if len(q.out) == q.capacity {
        <-q.out
    }
    q.out <- value
}

func (q *StackBuffer[T]) Pop() <-chan T {
    return q.out
}

func (q *StackBuffer[T]) Close() {
    close(q.out)
}


Тестовый код:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    queue := NewStackBuffer[int](5)

    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 100; i++ {
            queue.Push(i)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1000)) * time.Millisecond)
        }
        queue.Close()
    }()

    for v := range queue.Pop() {
        fmt.Printf("Pops from channel value: %d\n", v)
        time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(2000)) * time.Millisecond)
    }
}



Если продюсер один, должно работать, да
